# Handling errors: "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred", can these be ignored/averaged out in a simulation with many trials?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, model, separation

I have been getting the following errors in `R` because of trying to fit propensity scores that are well-stratified. I am currently looping over a model simulation 1000 times and in a portion of those I am getting:

```
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

I understand that other threads have handled this problem. However, I am seeking input into two strategies I have:

1. Only keep coefficients of those models without the error.
2. Ignore and let the averaging do its work

My question is, if I do a simulation 1000 times and observe that, say 50 of those resulted in errors, would it result in biasing if I were to just drop those 50 that resulted in the error?

Additionally, if I just average over those estimated coefficients, would it cause any problems?

Would either these methods be valid?

Comment: I don't have any useful references at the moment, but FWIW, when I do bootstrap analyses, sometimes the model does not converge. I generally drop those and use the rest for bootstrap analyses. The popular SEM package `lavaan` also does this by default and doesn't even throw a warning; instead, there is just a line on the output that will say something like "X out of Y resamples converged."